Method to solve maximazation optimization problems where f is convex under linear constraints
Could someone tell me a method, to solve an optimization problem of following form:
$$\text{maximize } f(x_1, x_2, x_3)$$
$$\text{under } x_i \geq 0, i = 1,2,3$$
$$h(x_1,x_2,x_3) = 0$$
Where f is convex and h linear?
